# Is this integral always valid?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, quantum-field-theory, divergent-integrals

The following integral was integrated using Mathematica:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\tau \frac{1}{(x^2+\tau^2)^a} = \frac{\Gamma(a-1/2)}{\Gamma(a)}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{|x|^{2 a -1}} \tag{1}$$

Mathematica says that this formula holds if $x^2\geq 0$ and $a>1/2$. I have the feeling that Mathematica gives the second condition to prevent divergent integrals ($\Gamma(\epsilon) \to \infty$ for $\epsilon \to 0$). However in my case, this integral showed up in the context of dimensional regularization, and $a=a(\omega)$ with $d=2\omega \to 4$ the number of dimensions. I am interested in values of $a\leq 1/2$, and would like to keep the divergence in the form of a gamma function as in $(1)$. Can I do that, or is the result of the integral something else for $a\leq 1/2$?

Comment: The whole point of dimensional regularization in QFT is to analytically continue to the desired region, replacing the integral with this function.

Comment: @J.G. Right, so it's not a problem to use this formula? I got scared by the Mathematica condition, but it's probably just because it is considering $a$ as some constant number.

Comment: It's essentially the example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect#Derivation_of_Casimir_effect_assuming_zeta-regularization).

Comment: @J.G. I see, thanks a lot!

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{d\tau}{(x^2+\tau^2)^a}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^{-2a}d\tau}{\left(\frac{\tau^2}{x^2}+1\right)^a}$$
now using $\frac \tau x=\tan u$ we get:
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{x^{1-2a}\sec^2(u)du}{\sec^{2a}(u)}=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}x^{1-2a}\sec^{2-2a}(u)du$$
Hopefully you can see any restrictions from this